# Can I use Nvidia GPU on ubuntu-core-22 and use ubuntu-frame for display?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ubuntu-core

I have a computer with an Nvidia GT 1030 graphics card, and I'm trying to use ubuntu-frame to display a simple website. Initially, the prompt is displayed without any issues. However, when I attempt to display something more complex using ubuntu-frame, I encounter a blank screen.

I installed `nvidia-core22` and `ubuntu-frame` (channel=22/stable), connecting them using `snap connect ubuntu-frame:graphics-core22 nvidia-core22:graphics-core22` to utilize Nvidia drivers with `ubuntu-frame`.

The `ubuntu-frame` logs are as follows:

```
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z systemd[1]: Started Service for snap application ubuntu-frame.daemon.
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1841]: ++ snapctl get display
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: + '[' -z '' ']'
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1847]: + initialise-display-config
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: + disown
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1848]: + sh -c 'sleep 5; mkdir "/run/user/007"; rmdir "/run/user/007"'
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: + exec nohup /snap/ubuntu-frame/5776/bin/run-frame /snap/ubuntu-frame/5776/bin/graphics-core22-wrapper /snap/ubuntu-frame/5776/usr/local/bin/frame
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: + [ /snap/ubuntu-frame/5776/bin/graphics-core22-wrapper = --help ]
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1853]: + dirname /run/user/0/snap.ubuntu-frame
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1849]: Setting up watches.
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1849]: Watches established.
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: + XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: + export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: + mkdir -p /run/user/0 -m 700
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: + [ -n  ]
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: + exec /snap/ubuntu-frame/5776/bin/graphics-core22-wrapper /snap/ubuntu-frame/5776/usr/local/bin/frame
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: [2023-06-27 12:43:46.347553] <information> mirserver: Starting
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: [2023-06-27 12:43:46.347935] < - debug - > mirserver: Using Linux VT subsystem for session management
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: [2023-06-27 12:43:46.348063] <information> mircommon: Loading modules from: /snap/ubuntu-frame/5776/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mir/server-platform
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: [2023-06-27 12:43:46.348116] <information> mircommon: Loading module: /snap/ubuntu-frame/5776/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mir/server-platform/graphics-eglstream-kms.so.20
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: [2023-06-27 12:43:46.348133] <information> mircommon: Loading module: /snap/ubuntu-frame/5776/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mir/server-platform/graphics-gbm-kms.so.20
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: [2023-06-27 12:43:46.348146] <information> mircommon: Loading module: /snap/ubuntu-frame/5776/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mir/server-platform/server-x11.so.20
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: [2023-06-27 12:43:46.348158] <information> mircommon: Loading module: /snap/ubuntu-frame/5776/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mir/server-platform/input-evdev.so.8
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: [2023-06-27 12:43:46.349104] <information> mirserver: Found display driver: mir:eglstream-kms (version 2.13.0)
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: [2023-06-27 12:43:46.358932] < - debug - > eglstream: Found EGLDeviceEXT with device extensions: EGL_MESA_device_software EGL_EXT_device_drm_render_node
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: [2023-06-27 12:43:46.359002] <information> eglstream: Failed to query DRM node for EGLDevice: Failed to determine DRM device node path from EGLDevice: EGL_BAD_PARAMETER (0x300c)
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: [2023-06-27 12:43:46.359015] < - debug - > eglstream: EGLDeviceEXTs found, but none are suitable for Mir
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: [2023-06-27 12:43:46.359033] <information> mirserver: (Unsupported by system environment)
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: [2023-06-27 12:43:46.359044] <information> mirserver: Found display driver: mir:gbm-kms (version 2.13.0)
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: [2023-06-27 12:43:46.359170] <information> gbm-kms: Unsupported: No DRM devices detected
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: [2023-06-27 12:43:46.359183] <information> mirserver: (Unsupported by system environment)
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: [2023-06-27 12:43:46.359194] <information> mirserver: Found display driver: mir:x11 (version 2.13.0)
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: [2023-06-27 12:43:46.359223] <information> mirserver: (Unsupported by system environment)
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: ERROR: ./src/server/graphics/default_configuration.cpp(233): Throw in function virtual const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<mir::graphics::DisplayPlatform> >& mir::DefaultServerConfiguration::the_display_platforms()
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: Dynamic exception type: boost::wrapexcept<std::runtime_error>
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: std::exception::what: Exception while creating graphics platform
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: ERROR: ./src/server/graphics/platform_probe.cpp(190): Throw in function std::vector<std::pair<mir::graphics::SupportedDevice, std::shared_ptr<mir::SharedLibrary> > > {anonymous}::modules_for_device({anonymous}::ModuleType, const std::vector<std::shared_ptr<mir::SharedLibrary> >&, const mir::options::ProgramOption&, const std::shared_ptr<mir::ConsoleServices>&)
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: Dynamic exception type: boost::wrapexcept<std::runtime_error>
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z ubuntu-frame.daemon[1817]: std::exception::what: Failed to find any platforms for current system
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z systemd[1]: snap.ubuntu-frame.daemon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
2023-06-27T12:43:46Z systemd[1]: snap.ubuntu-frame.daemon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

As far as I understand, GMB can't be used with Nvidia cards but EGL can.

Does someone has the same issue? Do you have any idea on how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know `nvidia-core22` and `ubuntu-frame` works on classic Ubuntu (Server or Desktop), but you need a kernel snap with Nvidia support for this to work on Ubuntu Core.

In addition, you need the `pc-kernel` and `nvidia-assemble` snaps to assemble and load nvidia kernelspace driver. (Thanks to [Xnox for this clarification](https://github.com/MirServer/ubuntu-frame/issues/143#issuecomment-1611035308)!)

This is inconvenient, but reflects limitations in the way that Nvidia Linux support can be packaged